# Is it a good practice to include a timestamp on an intranet portal?

Tags: intranet

I just want to know your opinion on having a **timestamp** in the header of an intranet portal.

Comment: It is hard to answer this question, because the answer depends on the context. Could you provide more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not really seen timestamps included on intranet portals for the benefit of the general internal staff. I wonder if it is a relic from designs in the past where this information was of some importance. Apparently they provide a piece of useful diagnostic information for technical support.

Hence if you do consider including it in your design, it is about finding a balance between how to make the information accessible to users without it being intrusive. Therefore, it is often placed in the top right or bottom left corner in a fixed position so it is easy for the technical support people to ask users to locate.